# Adjective to describe a person who is easy to work with

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What singular word can be used, to describe a person who is "easy to work with?"

Example sentences are

- *______ people are easy to work with*.
- *It's easy to work with John, he's very ______.*

Comment: A person could be easy to work with because they are friendly, or because they are knowledgeable, or because you generally hate people a lot but this one person is invisible, or because they are visible at all times licking your boots and you like *that*. It is unclear what you are after. The only words that reliably describe an easy-to-work-with person in all situations are "easy to work with". There is nothing wrong with using several words. That is what language is *all about*.

Comment: Tractable? "our preschool teachers disagree with the statement that children are becoming less tractable every year" (ODO)

Answer (score 4):

I think a good word would be:

- Agreeable

Other possibilities:

- laid back
- easy going